# Custom Data model shows old textures but slighty darkened

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I am trying to write a custom data model for a Trident at number 10, that will obtain a trident with a custom texture (stobie_trident.png). The problem is that it loads the default texture but slightly darkened.

Here is the models/item/trident.json

```
{
  "parent": "item/generated",
  "textures": {
    "layer0": "item/trident"
  },
  "overrides": [
    { "predicate": {"custom_model_data": 10}, "model": "custom/stobie_item"}
  ]
}
```

Here is the models/custom/stobie_item.json

```
{
  "parent": "item/generated",
  
  "textures": {
    "layer0": "custom/stobie_trident"
  }
}
```

My png file is save in textures/custom/stobie_trident.png
[image: stobie_trident.png][image: The texture I'm trying to add]

If I load it with `/give my_name trident(CustomModelData:10)` it just has the normal texture but faded.

Comment: Can you post your texture file? Or see what's in the alpha channel (I don't know if Minecraft works with those, but still)?

Comment: The texture works fine if I write it's link in the trident's texture field but not from the stobie_item.json

Comment: If I open up stobie_item.json in blockbench, it works fine.